# Mocking out the Data Accessor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inversion-of-control, moq

I am trying to learn about using Moq with NUnit and IoC.

(I have my full project in BitBucket, but not sure how to share it...)
https://bitbucket.org/Cralis/skeleton/overview

I have a Logic method (Login) I am trying to test. It take a request object (Which has a username, password and IP Address). If the username and/or password are empty, the logic returns a failed status, and doesn't go to the data access layer.

So I am creating a unit test to test this.
(This my my first attempt with mocking...)

```
 public void NotNull_Returns_True()
        {
            // Arrange
            var request = new LoginRequest { IPAddress = "1.1.1.1", Username = "dummy", Password = "dummy" };
            var response = new LoginResponse { Request = request, Success = true, Message = "", UserID = 1 };

            // Setup the moc data accessor, as we don't want to gop to the concrete one.
            var MockedDataAccess = new Mock<IDataAccess>();

            // Set it's return value
            MockedDataAccess.Setup(x => x.Login(request)).Returns(response);

            // Instantiate the Logic class we're testing, using a Moc data accessor.
            var logic = new BusinessLogic(MockedDataAccess.Object);

            // Act
            var result = logic.Login(new LoginRequest { Password = "dummy", Username = "dummy", IPAddress = "1.1.1.1" });

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(true, result.Success);
        }
```

This fails on the assert, as 'result' is NULL.

I'm probably doing a lot wrong. For example, I'm not sure why I need to setup the request and response objects at the top,but because all the examples I find are 'string' and 'int' inputs, it seems I can't use It.IsAny...

Could someone assist me understanding here? What am I doing wrong to get NULL as a result in the assert? I step through and the code executes as expected. But the result is null, because I never called the data accessor (It used the mock).

Edit:
Ah,

```
// Set it's return value
            MockedDataAccess.Setup(x => x.Login(It.IsAny<LoginRequest>())).Returns(response);
```

That resolved the issue. I'm not sure why, so if you can help me understand and refactor this so that it's as an experienced Moq/UnitTester would expect it to look, that would be very useful.

Comment: What does your `Login` method do?  Does it call methods on your `IDataAccess` dependency, and return null if those methods return null?

Comment: @BenRubin - I've added a Bitbucket link, so you can see it all and clone. But basically if there is null values sent to the BL layer, it evaluates and returns a Response object with the success flag being False. It shouldn't ever return a null object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your `request` object has the same property values that you're passing to `var result = logic.Login(new LoginRequest { Password = "dummy", Username = "dummy", IPAddress = "1.1.1.1" });`, they are different objects, and so the value that you're trying to return with `MockedDataAccess.Setup(x => x.Login(request)).Returns(response);` isn't getting returned.

Change

```
var result = logic.Login(new LoginRequest { Password = "dummy", Username = "dummy", IPAddress = "1.1.1.1" });
```

to

```
var result = logic.Login(request);
```

The reason it worked with `MockedDataAccess.Setup(x => x.Login(It.IsAny<LoginRequest>())).Returns(response);` is because now you're saying *"when `MockedDataAccess.Login` is called with **any** value for its parameter, return `response`"*

Regarding the second part of your question, the reason that you need to set up the request and response objects is that by default any method that you call on a mock object will return null.  Your `BusinessLogic.Login` method, listed below, will return the value of `dataAccess.Login()`.  Since `dataAccess` is a mock, the `dataAccess.Login()` method will return null unless you tell it otherwise.

```
    public LoginResponse Login(LoginRequest request)
    {

        // Basic validation
        if (request == null)
            return new LoginResponse
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = "Empty Request"
            };

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Password))
            return new LoginResponse
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = "Username and/or password empty"
            };

        // This is returning null since dataAccess is a mock
        return dataAccess.Login(request);
    }
```

You said you think you're doing a lot wrong, but the way you have the test set up is pretty much what I do.  The only thing I would change (in addition to fixing the `Setup` method as described above) is to use the *UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior*  naming pattern for your test.  For example `Login_ValidLoginRequest_ShouldReturnValidLoginResponse()`

Comment: Thanks @BenRubin - That all makes a lot of sense and helps me on my learning path and provides some validation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this code

`var result = logic.Login(new LoginRequest { Password = "dummy", Username = "dummy", IPAddress = "1.1.1.1" })`

is that in the implementation of the `Login` method this is called

`dataAccess.Login(request)`

It means you have to setup the mock of `DataAccess` for method `Login` because mock does otherwise nothing. Mock if *fake* and needs to be setup so it works the way you need. In this case the answer of @Ben Rubin is absolutely correct.

When mock is setup like this

`MockedDataAccess.Setup(x => x.Login(request)).Returns(response)`

then it is necessary to call the method under test with exactly the same request object as the request which was used in setup of data access `Login` method, because otherwise mock will act as not setup. Here you basically saying *'when DataAccess Login is called with exactly this request, that response will be returned'.*

But when mock is setup like this

`MockedDataAccess.Setup(x => x.Login(It.IsAny<LoginRequest>())).Returns(response)`

then it works, because here `Login` is setup to any `LoginRequest`. So the mock will in this case return `response` no matter what request was used. HTH

Here are more information about [Mock Matching Arguments](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments)